# Change format from c language to c++

Tags: c++, c

How can I convert the below statement from c language into c++ language

```
Char_t message[80];
sprintf(message,"Total : #chi^{2}/NDF = %.2f",fun->GetChisquare()/fun->GetNDF());
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: do you need to change it? It will work just fine in cpp code, if you include the right headers.

Comment: maybe from C++ to C ? :-)

Comment: pretty much the definition of a question that can't possibly help future visitors; voting to close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you could do something like this

```
#include <sstream>

stringstream ss;
ss << std::fixed;
ss << "Total : #chi^{2}/NDF = " 
   << setprecision(2) 
   << fun->GetChisquare()/fun->GetNDF();

string message(ss.str());
```

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing you need to do. It's legal C++ as is.

Answer (score 2):

Do nothing. This looks like valid C++ code.